# How to find the maximum nesting depth of a S-expression in scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket

for example

```
(nestFind '(a(b)((c))d e f)) => 3

(nestFind '()) => 0

(nestFind '(a b)) => 1

(nestFind '((a)) )=> 2

(nestFind '(a (((b c d))) (e) ((f)) g)) => 4
```

this is what i tried so far but its not working properly:

```
(define (nestFind a)
  (cond
    ((null? a)0)
    ((atom? a)0)
    ((atom? (car a))(+ 1 (nestFind (cdr a))))
    (else
     (+(nestFind (car a))(nestFind (cdr a))))))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit simpler. Give this a try:

```
(define (nestFind lst)
  (if (not (pair? lst))
      0
      (max (add1 (nestFind (car lst)))
           (nestFind (cdr lst)))))
```

The trick is using [`max`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._max%29%29) to find out which branch of the recursion is the deepest, noticing that each time we recur on the `car` we add one more level. Alternatively, a solution closer to what you intended - but once again, `max` proves helpful:

```
(define (nestFind lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
        ((atom? lst) 0)
        (else (max (+ 1 (nestFind (car lst)))
                   (nestFind (cdr lst))))))
```

Either way, it'll work as expected for the sample input:

```
(nestFind '())
=> 0
(nestFind '(a b))
=> 1
(nestFind '((a)))
=> 2
(nestFind '(a (b) ((c)) d e f))
=> 3
(nestFind '(a (((b c d))) (e) ((f)) g))
=> 4
```

Comment: is it possible to do it without using max.

Comment: @xmantra23 I don't think so, it's either `max` or an `if` expression that does basically the same. After all we're not interested in _adding_ the number of elements (that's what you were doing), just in finding the depth of the deepest sublist

Comment: (or (null? lst) (not (pair? lst))) can be written just as (not (pair? lst)). The same for (null? lst) and (atom? lst).

Comment: @jJ' you're right, thanks! that simplifies things a bit more. I updated my proposed solution, but I'll leave the other one as-is, because it's more in line with OP's initial implementation.